# Running Rails server on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rubygems, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to get rails running on Ubuntu (11.04). I've installed my gems and whatnot -- I can see all of them thru 'gem list'. However, when I run the command rails s or rails server, rails for some reason tries to create a new app called 's' or 'server' (respectively) instead of running the server. Any advice?

Comment: I would recommend following this guide to set up your machine: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/. I think you've probably installed the packages via aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

check the output of `rails -v`, it'll probably report rails 2.3.x - that will be your problem.

Comment: Thanks but my problem isn't fully solved... For some reason my gem list says I have rails 3.0.7 and 3.0.9 but not rails 2.3 of any kind. Yet rails -v gives 2.3.5. How do I change this??

Comment: have a look at the output of 'which rails' - that's what is being run when you run rails -v. You'll want to move your gem paths to higher in your PATH to have your installed gems run first.